# Select specific Tumblr XML values with PHP

Tags: php, xml, tumblr

My goal is to embed Tumblr posts into a website using their provided XML. The problem is that Tumblr saves 6 different sizes of each image you post. My code below will get the first image, but it happens to be too large. How can I select one of the smaller-sized photos out of the XML if all the photos have the same tag of `<photo-url>`?

→ This is the XML from my Tumblr that I'm using: [Tumblr XML](http://kthornbloom.tumblr.com/api/read?type=photo).

→ This is my PHP code so far:

```
<?php
$request_url = "http://kthornbloom.tumblr.com/api/read?type=photo";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
$title = $xml->posts->post->{'photo-caption'};
$photo = $xml->posts->post->{'photo-url'};
echo '<h1>'.$title.'</h1>';
echo '<img src="'.$photo.'"/>"'; 
echo "…";
echo "</br><a target=frame2 href='".$link."'>Read More</a>"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getPhoto` takes an array of `$photos` and a `$desiredWidth`. It returns the photo whose `max-width` is (1) closest to and (2) less than or equal to `$desiredWidth`. You can adapt the function to fit your needs. The important things to note are:

- `$xml->posts->post->{'photo-url'}` is an array.
- `$photo['max-width']` accesses the `max-width` attribute on the `<photo>` tag.

I used `echo '<pre>'; print_r($xml->posts->post); echo '</pre>';` to find out `$xml->posts->post->{'photo-url'}` was an array.

I found the syntax for accessing attributes (e.g., `$photo['max-width']`) at the documentation for [`SimpleXMLElement`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.count.php).

```
function getPhoto($photos, $desiredWidth) {
    $currentPhoto = NULL;
    $currentDelta = PHP_INT_MAX;
    foreach ($photos as $photo) {
        $delta = abs($desiredWidth - $photo['max-width']);
        if ($photo['max-width'] <= $desiredWidth && $delta < $currentDelta) {
            $currentPhoto = $photo;
            $currentDelta = $delta;
        }
    }
    return $currentPhoto;
}

$request_url = "http://kthornbloom.tumblr.com/api/read?type=photo";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);

foreach ($xml->posts->post as $post) {
    echo '<h1>'.$post->{'photo-caption'}.'</h1>';
    echo '<img src="'.getPhoto($post->{'photo-url'}, 450).'"/>"'; 
    echo "...";
    echo "</br><a target=frame2 href='".$post['url']."'>Read More</a>"; 
}
```

Comment: PERFECT. One last question if you don't mind- how would I write this to print out each of my posts rather than just the most recent?

Comment: Another `foreach` loop should do the trick. I updated my answer.

Comment: Also, I replaced `$link` with `$post['url']`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the photo with `max-width="100"`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('tumblr.xml');

echo '<h1>'.$xml->posts->post->{'photo-caption'}.'</h1>';

foreach($xml->posts->post->{'photo-url'} as $url) {
    if ($url->attributes() == '100')
        echo '<img src="'.$url.'" />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
$doc = simplexml_load_file(
  'http://kthornbloom.tumblr.com/api/read?type=photo'
);

foreach ($doc->posts->post as $post) {
  foreach ($post->{'photo-url'} as $photo_url) {
    echo $photo_url;
    echo "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but this seems to print out every single photo. In the XML, wish I could select <photo-url max-width="250"> out of each post.