# Tumblr XML not loading

Tags: php, simplexml, tumblr

I implemented the following code based on some code I found in another question:
[Select specific Tumblr XML values with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853851/select-specific-tumblr-xml-values-with-php)

```
function getPhoto($photos, $desiredWidth) {
$currentPhoto = NULL;
$currentDelta = PHP_INT_MAX;
foreach ($photos as $photo) {
    $delta = abs($desiredWidth - $photo['max-width']);
    if ($photo['max-width'] <= $desiredWidth && $delta < $currentDelta) {
        $currentPhoto = $photo;
        $currentDelta = $delta;
    }
}
return $currentPhoto;
}

$request_url = "http://ACCOUNT.tumblr.com/api/read?type=photo&start=0&num=30";
//$request_url = "tumblr.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);

foreach ($xml->posts->post as $post) {
echo "<div class=\"item\"><a href='".$post['url']."'><img src='".getPhoto($post->{'photo-url'}, 250)."' width=\"250\" /></a></div>"; 
}
```

This code worked just fine on my development site, but when I pushed it live on another server, it would not load the external XML from Tumblr... It loaded the local text XML just fine (commented out in the code).

I'm waiting to get the account credentials from the client, so I can contact customer service and work with them...

In the meantime, does anyone have any ideas what might cause this?
Server settings?
Missing PHP code?

Comment: It appears the hosting environment has the following settings:
allow_url_fopen: OFF
allow_url_include: OFF

cURL is enabled... I'm a bit of a hack, but through Google I've come to the conclusion that this is an alternative way to achieve the same thing, yet safer...

Any advice on how to translate the code to cURL? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up using cURL to load the XML... Here's the code that worked:

```
function getPhoto($photos, $desiredWidth) {
    $currentPhoto = NULL;
    $currentDelta = PHP_INT_MAX;
    foreach ($photos as $photo) {
        $delta = abs($desiredWidth - $photo['max-width']);
        if ($photo['max-width'] <= $desiredWidth && $delta < $currentDelta) {
            $currentPhoto = $photo;
            $currentDelta = $delta;
        }
    }
    return $currentPhoto;
}

$url="http://ACCOUNT.tumblr.com/api/read?type=photo&start=0&num=30";
$ch = curl_init();      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // get the url contents

$data = curl_exec($ch); // execute curl request
curl_close($ch); // close curl request

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);

foreach($xml->posts->post as $post) {
    echo "<div class=\"item\"><a href='".$post['url']."'><img src='".getPhoto($post->{'photo-url'}, 250)."' width=\"250\" /></a></div>"; 
}
```